# jQuery fade toggle image within a class

Tags: jquery, image, html, toggle, fade

A few hitches in a bit of my code. I've got several HTML5 audio players on a page, each of which is played by clicking on an image that fades in when you enter its container. To accomodate the use of the same play image on all the players, I made it a class.

My issue is that when you fade into any of the .thumbnail containers the image fades in. I need to somehow hone it in to whichever container you entered.. maybe with (this) or something.

HTML:

```
        <div class="thumbnail" id="paparazzi">
            <a class="playback">
                <img class="play" src="http://www.lucisz.com/imgs/play.png" />
            </a>
            <audio>
                <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
            </audio>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.play').hide();
$('.thumbnail').hover(function(){
    $('.play').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Conceptual JavaScript:

```
$('.play').hide();
$('this, .thumbnail').hover(function(){
    $('.play').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Comment: Create a jsFiddle with your html, js, and css and we can help fix it.

Comment: @Scott http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/66FwR/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be this:

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function(e){
    $('.play', this).fadeToggle(400);
});
```

So you were nearly right.

For an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4NYqv/4/

Edit: Sorry, had it the wrong way around.

Comment: @Henry Garle doesn't quite work as I'd like, but I think it's my theory behind it. the thumbnail image (which i css'd light violet in the jsfiddle) should stay in, and just the play class image should fade in and out. http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/4NYqv/2/

Comment: @henry Garle yes, exactly. I accepted your answer, please update it with your jsFiddle function. I understand what it was.. had to filter play class, within THIS, not this and the play class. smart.

Comment: Yeah I only just noticed, sorry about that!

Comment: No worries. I'm about to post another question on how to stop the animation if it's currently animated.. i.e. if you run your mouse back and forth over the thumbnails a bunch and then stop they keep animating.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722758/jquery-fadetoggle-if-currently-animated-ignore-further-input

Comment: You might want to put `.stop(true,true)` prior to your `.fadeToggle` in your jQuery chain to eliminate animation queuing.

Comment: I guess I should've looked at your question and answered it there, haha. Oh well. I guess I was using ESPn. Slight sports/psychic joke there.