# jQuery fadeToggle if currently animated, ignore further input

Tags: jquery, hover, toggle, fade, if-statement

I've got some thumbnails that have a play button that fades in on top of them when you hover. My issue is that when you hover over them repeatedly, say three times, they fade in and out three times. I once ran into a jQuery function that included an if then statement roughly saying if it's animated disregard further input.. But I'm not sure what the syntax is to do such a thing.

Ideas? Thank you!

Here's a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/66FwR/10/

HTML:

```
<div id="music_right">
        <div class="thumbnail" id="paparazzi">
            <a class="playback">
                <img class="play" src="http://www.lucisz.com/imgs/play.png" />
               </a>
            <audio>
                   <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
            </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail" id="danceinthedark">
            <a class="playback">
                <img class="play" src="http://www.lucisz.com/imgs/play.png" />
               </a>
            <audio>
                   <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_danceinthedark.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_danceinthedark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
            </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail" id="bornthisway">
            <a class="playback">
                <img class="play" src="http://www.lucisz.com/imgs/play.png" />
               </a>
            <audio>
                   <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_bornthisway.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_bornthisway.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.play').hide();
$('.thumbnail').hover(function(){
    $('.play', this).fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
$('.play', this).fadeToggle(400);
```

to

```
$('.play', this).stop(true,true).fadeToggle(400);
```

your updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/66FwR/12/

---

The if statement you mention is by using the [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector.

it would look something like

```
if ( $('.play',this).is(':animated') )
{
 // do whatever..
}
```

but that will not work in your case, because if you hover out while the button is still fading-**in**, then the fade-out will not queue and the play button will stay on forever..

Comment: @Gaby awesome. Such a simple approach! Do you mind explaining the (true,true) part of the function? Forgive my lack of nomenclature.

Comment: @technopeasant - The first true clears the animation queue. The second true jumps to the end of the animation.

Comment: Yes this answer is perfect and simple but like my answer stated,animate is more flexible ad if you ever have to add anything else in (ie the padding) you don't have to do extra, everything is already built in

Answer (score 1):

This is due to queueing of the event. The way I will usually do it like this:

```
$(".thumbnail").hover(function(){
    $(".play", this).stop().animate({opacity:1}, "fast");
}, function(){
    $(".play", this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, "fast");
});
```

the stop() does what it sounds like. Stops all animation and since jQuery's chains, calls the animate after the object has stopped.

You don't get the toggle method but I rather doing it this way because of the control I get in jQuery's animate method.