# How do I prevent jQuery .hover function from affecting all images simultaneously?

Tags: jquery-hover, jquery

I'm not sure the title explains it well enough, but was trying to keep it quite short!

So, I've got a number of images scattered around a page and have created a lightbox gallery for them all (.cboxElement is the class that calls it).  What i wanted to add into this was a hover effect on each image affected by the lightbox so the user knows it can be zoomed.

The problem:

I didn't write the original code for the site and this is a new feature.  Due to inconsistencies in classes across images, I had to prepend a  tag before each image with a unique class for the hover method to refer to, as follows:

```
    $("a.cboxElement").each(function(){
        $(this).prepend("<span class='zoom'></span>");
    });
```

Immediately following this, I've used the hover effect:

```
    $("a.cboxElement").hover(function(){
        $("a.cboxElement span").fadeIn('fast');
    },
    function(){
        $("a.cboxElement span").fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

The problem is that when I hover over an image on the page, the hover effect appears on every image simultaneously and I can't work out how to get it to affect only the image I'm hovering over.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could do?

Many thanks,

Jon

Comment: bit new to this so hoping i'm putting this in the right place!

just wanted to add something else i noticed for anyone finding this thread useful, by adding .stop(true,true) after the .find it immediately stops the current animation and starts the next - useful if someone hovers on/off before the previous effect has finished, otherwise the animation is not in time with the users actions. found info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722758/jquery-fadetoggle-if-currently-animated-ignore-further-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to change the scope of your hover assignment:

```
$("a.cboxElement").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("span").fadeIn('fast');
},
function(){
    $(this).find("span").fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Your original code was saying: for each `a.cboxElement`, find all `a.cboxElement` elements' `span`s and fade them in/out. The above code says for each `a.cboxElement`, on hover, find the `span` for just *this* `a.cboxElement` and fade it in/out.

Comment: Cheers Cory, works perfectly!  And thanks for explaining what my original code was actually saying, very useful

Comment: @Jon, you're welcome, and welcome to SO. For answers you find helpful and accurate, please remember to click the checkmark next to it to mark them as the "Accepted" answer.

Comment: @CoryAll done - wouldn't let me vote up yet though, not enough rep!

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use [`.fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) with a single function:

```
$("a.cboxElement").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("span").fadeToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: As soon as I saw this I thought, yes, that's what I should've have done - but for some reason it doesn't work...I'll play around with it and see what I get, but cheers for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Assign an `id="..."` attribute to each image and select it instead of the entire `a.cboxElement` class:

```
<img id="imageid1" ... >
$('#imageid1')....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.cboxElement").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('span:first').fadeIn('fast');
},
function(){
    $(this).find('span:first').fadeOut('fast');
});
```